# Deleting cell conditionally with apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm having trouble with what seems like a very simple problem. Yet, I don't know how to fix it.

I am trying to clear cell A2 if and only if A1 is empty. I'm sure there is an easy solution but I don't seem to notice it. I'll share a sample spreadsheet for all of you to visualize my objective.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qiq0w4xcUDO8pkFyeMO2ma_KR48evSsVAP6o50O0RtI/edit#gid=0

This is what I tried.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("TEST");
  var range = e.source.getActiveRange();

  if(e.range.getRow() == 1 && e.range.getColumn() == 1) {
    if(sheet.getRange("A1").getValue() == "") {
      sheet.getRange('A2').clearContent();    
    }
  }   
 }
```

Is there any problem with what I'm doing?

Help would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below works for me. I think you might be getting the selected range which may be different? Also you might not want to run this on other sheets? If performance becomes an issue, it might make sense to reduce the `&&` statements and use more if statements.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const range = e.range;
  const zzSheetName = "TEST";
  const ss = range.getSheet();

  if(ss.getName() == zzSheetName
    && ss.getRange("A1").isBlank()
    && range.getRow()==1 
    && range.getColumn()==1
    && (!ss.getRange("A2").isBlank())
    ){
      ss.getRange('A2').clearContent();    
    }
 }
```

Comment: One more question though. Is there a way to use myFunction() or something else instead of edit trigger? I already have an onEdit(e) for something else and the problem is that if I use another trigger for this, the previous one doesn't seem to activate.

I did try myFunction(), but then it doesn't activate....

Answer (score 0):

Clear A2 if A1 is empty

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "TEST" && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart == 1 && e.value === '') {
    e.range.offset(0, 1).clearContent();
  }
}
```